# Getting list of allowable previewThumbnails for a google+ post with a link

Tags: google-plus

We are trying to create a google+ post that contains a link. The link should have a preview thumbnail image that goes with it.

The api documentation says we just need to set the attachment.image.url to what we want the preview image to be, but it has to come from the set of allowable previewThumbnails. Here's the doc I'm referring to: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities

How can we get the set of allowable images?

This page: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/faq suggests that we must use an "activity preview request" to get the list, but the link in that page doesn't go somewhere that tells us how to do this.